Develop programs on the beta playground and test with localhost frontend
Hi guys I was trying to install my environment to get started working on solana programs on my windows machine. Unfortunately I have came across so many errors and it's just an endless circle at this point.
I was wondering if I can develop my program using the Solana Playground, deploy my program on the test net from this platform and then on my machine windows interact with the program using a react app running in local?
If I remember correctly I use to do this with Solidity smart contracts but I am not sure if it works for Solana programs.

were you using WSL on windows? Feel free to create a question with the errors you faced.

Yes I was but fore some reason I have problem with ts-node on it. When I create a project with anchor init. If I try inside the project to run a ts command such as console.log('test') it returns error Cannot find name console. If I execute the same command outisde the project directory I have no problem. TS and ts-node are both installed globally and in the project itself

did you want to run a single test file? what's the reason for running ts-node inside the project?

I want to execute a test file yes

if that's the case, you can use anchor run. Check out https://github.com/SoundWorkLabs/marketplace-contracts/blob/168fd42a3d65d80afc4a0864606ae83226bce2c2/Anchor.toml#L23-L26 for an example

Runing anchor test or anchor run will give me the same error as running with tsnode

please create a new question with the error.

Build your anchor project to generate the IDL and types.
anchor build

In the root of your anchor project, copy the types directory to a desired location on your front end, e.g idl
cp -r target/types/program_name idl

note: here program_name is your types file and it's usually named after your project name in snake_case.ts
In your frontend app, import the types and idl. The IDL is exported as IDL while the types use the name of your program as Pascal Casing e.g if you anchor init anchor-test your types will be exported as AnchorTest
import { ProgramName as programName, IDL as programNameIDL } from "./idl/program_name";

Generate your Anchor program instance
const program = new Program<programName>(
    programNameIDL,
    PROGRAM_NAME_ID, 
    provider // Anchor Provider
);

Then call the program methods
let ix = await program.methods
    .initialize()
    .accounts({
        SystemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
    })
    .instruction();


Hi thanks for your reply. I tried this but I don't have the import from this line import { ProgramName as programName, IDL as programNameIDL } from "./idl/program_name";  it says cannot find module './idl/sol_program' (I replaced sol_program with the acuta name)

I switched some things around in the script and now it's working
